# What will be perfect hash fn. and smallest size hash for billions of URLs?

Tags: .net, url, hash

To index 100 billion URLs and further what has function will work perfect with no collisions. Since URLs are unique strings, i suppose any string hash func. like MD5 will be good, but need input from experts.

Also we want to search the URL set (DB table as of now) via hash, so obviously shorter hash will be efficient in search time and space.

Can i specify fixed hash-length ?

We are using C# .NET 4.0

Comment: I dare say that for 100 billion URLs, a perfect hash function is perhaps not what you want... besides, just because all these URLs are unique strings doesn't mean that their MD5 sums will be unique, too: *"[...] it has been shown that MD5 is not collision resistant"* (from the [Wikipedia article on MD5](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5)).

Comment: @stakx why you say perfect hash fn. is not what we shud target ? what are our choices then ? I hope google and other big URL indexes would be using index on trillions of URLs. so how tdo they do it ?

Comment: Perfect hashes don't seem suitable here because they have to be computed up-front. Afterwards, if *only one* out of your 100 billion URLs changes, you would have to recompute *all* hashes to guarantee that they're still unique. Thus I would assume that this is not how Google et al. maintain a URL index. Perfect hash functions, IIRC, are suitable for smaller, unchanging sets of values.

Comment: @stakx thnx 4 ur replies. you mean to say i shud live with collisions ? that means i would be rejecting or miscomputing some URLs. if i get  a new different URL, it goes through "AddOrUpdate in table" operation, so hash of this URL if collides with existing URL hash, then i may be overwriting (updating) some wrong data.  wont a 15 character(assuming, a-z, A-Z and 0-9 set) hash (with 62 pow 15 output space) and a good hash-algo ensure very rare collision ? (like 32 hex char GUID)

Comment: you seem to contradict yourself. Are collisions acceptable to you or not? I never argued anything against hash functions *per se* -- only against *perfect* hashing. Yes, a good hash algorithm (google e.g. for the hashing algorithms by Bob Jenkins) would seem fine. But there'll be that very small probability of collisions, and you need to find a way to deal or live with these. You could also compute two hashes per URL with two different algorithms and use them as a composite key in your DB table, that should reduce the chance of a (now double) hash collision even further.

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure your DB table isn't the way to go? That is a lot of requirements for a hash function. Most hash functions won't let you set the length of the hash, and requiring the hash to be perfect narrows it further. Do you need all of these requirements? More than likely, a much simpler solution will work just as well.

Are you reading this off disk? (100-billion URLS, assuming a URL length of 4 for a domain, + 4 for ".com" + "/" + 3 more = 12 bytes per URL = 1.09 TiB - and that is a very conservative estimate.) You might want to look into disk-friendlier structures, such as B-Trees (and their derivatives, such as B+-trees) - these data structures offer efficient (log(n) theoretically, but can beat hash-tables in some common cases) lookup, removal, insertion. Databases typically use these for indexes over hashes, which should give a hint as to their performance. (And which brings me back to my initial question: are you sure your DB table isn't the way to go?)

If you use a hash, even one with collisions will work. Something like SHA256, while being relatively expensive to calculate, will have a collision rate acceptably low. (I believe it's so low, you're more likely to be struck by lightning. Multiple times. People use UUIDs with no fear of collision, which have less than half as many bits as a SHA256 hash.) The CPU cost of a SHA256 might not matter, if you're going to follow it up with disk access.

(Also: is your DB table of URLs properly indexed to allow fast searching on that field?)

Comment: thnx 4 ur valuable advise. Well, its start of our project, so quick storage candidate for me is DB. I assume i just need to create an index over a field (here hash) for fast search and rest of the work will be done by DB. And as an edit, URL avg length  as mentioned in research is ~100 bytes. So as such URLs alone would amount to 10 TB leave alone their other accompanying data. that opens up the whole data storage problem for us anyway. But coming to this problem, as you said, SHA256.

Comment: fundamentally thats what the point i was truying to make in my above comments. 256 bit output space and a good algo should ensure rare collisions. Well, i am ok to live with rare collisions (if they cant be avoided), i assume no algo gives guarantee of being collision-free. So its like 32 byte hash for avg 100 byte url. this is imp. decision for me to make up-front, going with 128-bit or 256. Because if we are able to scale well for 100 billion, then we will target even much higher. So a future-proof solution and mitigation startegy needs to be thought somewhat now.

Comment: If you have your URL dataset available to you now, and you have the hardware (storage) to support it, I'd go ahead and set up the database. Getting a database of nothing but URLs up and running and setting up an index shouldn't take much time: I'd expect most of the time would be spent importing your data. Start with a small setup to get it working, then throw the real world set at it and stress test it. Theory can be discussed all day, but getting out there and getting your hands dirty should give you a good feel for it. Specific problems with particular software are then better SO questions.